# After adding objects via CoreDataGeneratedAccessors to-many relationships's NSSet is empty

Tags: core-data, relationship

I have two Core Data entities: `Parent` and `Child`. Parent has to-many relationship to a `Child` called `children`. Inverse relationship from is `Child.parent`. So parent has `CoreDataGeneratedAccessors`: `- (void)addChildrenObject:(Child *)value;` and `- (void)addChildren:(NSSet *)value;`.

Problem: after I add Child(s) by using one of those accessors and save managedObjectContext `parent.children` is empty. At the same time `parent` property of every added `Child` point to  proper instance of `Parent` and `NSFetchedResultsController` fetches such children (predicate is `parent = %@, <instance of Parent>`) well.

How can it be so? Just don't have a clue how to debug such a strange CoreData behavior.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to add the children to the parent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Somehow property of that set was sythesized by `@synthesize` not `@dynamic` in .m file. I know this was a very stupid typo, but I wonder why XCode did not even generated a warning about that! Static analyzer said nothing about it too!

Answer (score 0):

The same happens when you define properties like this:

```
@interface Project : BaseModel {
  Workspace *workspace;
  NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Workspace *workspace;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

Correct interface should look like this:

```
@interface Project : BaseModel {}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Workspace *workspace;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```