# CoreData: inverse relationship no set automatically

Tags: core-data, relationship

I've got a very strange situation: in one app I have lots of CoreData entities. Few pairs of them are connected by one-to-one relationships with inverse relationships. They are kind of parent-to-child relationships: so when parent is created I create child in it's `awakeFromInsert`. The problem is that in one of such relationships inverse `parent.child` is nil. And of course I've got error when trying to save managedObjectContext. Of course I can set this inverse relationship manually, but I wonder why it's not set automatically?

Comment: If when the parent is created you create the child in the parent's awakeFromInsert, then the parent.child is not the inverse relationship; a nil value there would indicate something wrong with the awakeFromInsert method. If the child.parent relationship is nil, then the problem is as you say. Does it happen with the very last parent you create or at random? Or does it happen when you create the child separately? If so, how are you assigning the child.parent relationship?

Comment: We don't have enough info to go on but I suspect it is related to the problem you describe in the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432771/after-adding-objects-via-coredatageneratedaccessors-to-many-relationshipss-nsset